# Django Failed to Import Test Module

Tags: python, django, django-testing, python-3.8

Trying to run this test file on a simple Django pages app from the book Django for Beginners. The book suggested importing SimpleTestCase bc there are no databases involved.

```html
# pages/tests.py

from django.test import SimpleTestCase

class PagesTests(SimpleTestCase):
    def test_home_page_status_code(self):
        response = self.client.get('/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_about_page_status_code(self):
        response = self.client.get('/about/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

And keep getting this error message:

```
ERROR: pages.tests (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: pages.tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pages.tests'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=3)
(pages) bash-3.2$ python3 manage.py test
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
EE
======================================================================
ERROR: pages.pages (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: pages.pages
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 470, in _find_test_path
    package = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pages.pages'


======================================================================
ERROR: pages.pages_project (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: pages.pages_project
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 470, in _find_test_path
    package = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pages.pages_project'
```

Looks like django can't find the test module.... at first i thought that it was getting confused bc there are two directories called 'pages', so I moved the tests.py file around with no luck. I also created a separate directory for tests ('No module called pages.test')

I also played with the two views.py files (pages/views.py and pages/pages/views.py) making them identical because I wasn't sure if that was the problem. Most SO searches don't yield results for Python 8, so wondering if that may somehow be a factor?

Here's my file tree:

```
    .
    ├── Pipfile
    ├── Pipfile.lock
    ├── pages
    │   ├── Pipfile
    │   ├── Pipfile.lock
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── db.sqlite3
    │   ├── manage.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── pages
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── admin.py
    │   │   ├── apps.py
    │   │   ├── migrations
    │   │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── models.py
    │   │   ├── urls.py
    │   │   └── views.py
    │   ├── pages_project
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── asgi.py
    │   │   ├── settings.py
    │   │   ├── urls.py
    │   │   └── wsgi.py
    │   ├── templates
    │   │   ├── about.html
    │   │   ├── base.html
    │   │   └── home.html
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── views.py
```

Comment: "Most SO searches don't yield results for Python 8" => well, it tooks 10 years or so for Python3 to replace Python2, so you shouldn't expect any resource about Python 8 before half a century xD

Comment: More seriously, it looks like you're confused with python's module search path (which is indeed not the best part of the language), and having both your project directory and your app named "pages" doesn't help either. And finally, the ImportError message can be misleading - you get the same message whatever prevents the module from being imported (syntax error or whatever else), even if the file is found.

Comment: First thing first: put your tests.py file back in the pages app (pages/pages directory), that's where it belongs, and remove the urls and views files at the root level (tehy also belong to pages/pages). Then launch your django shell (`./manage.py shell`),, type the following commands and edit your question with the results: 1/ `import sys; print(sys.path)` and 2/ `from pages import tests`.

Comment: @user3763074 did you find a solution to this ?